# How to open multiple files from different folders at once in cmd or powershell?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, powershell, sublime-text-2

I have 4 folders inside my directory: f1, f2, f3, f4. Each folder has the same structure inside. I have to open a file contained in each folder with the same name (f1 has some other folders inside and finally a file named "frr.conf", f2 has some other folders inside and finally a file named "frr.conf", f3 has some other folders inside and finally a file named "frr.conf" etc...)

The linux command is

```
gedit *\etc\frr\frr.conf
```

what's an equivalent for windows cmd or powershell? I want it to be opened with sublime so the only thing i know so far is that i should put "subl" keyword somewhere in the script

Comment: probably something like `gci . -r frr.conf | % { subl $_.FullName }`. the `.` is the current path. the `-r` searches recursively for `frr.conf` inside the path. not sure about the `subl` though, because i don't use sublime text. however, `$_.FullName` represents the full path as an argument

Comment: I'm going to try this and I'll let you know

Comment: Should i put the current path instead of "FullName" or FullName already does it?

Comment: Try this and you can see for yourself - `gci . -r frr.conf | % {$_.FullName}`

Comment: In a batch file you just have to put program that is going to open the file followed by complete path to the file it is going to open. Something like "C:\MyProgram.exe" "c:\my folder\fileToOpen.ffr.conf". If you have 4 files to open you put 4 lines like this inside the batch file.

Comment: @karalis1 - $_.FullName represents the full path to each found frr.conf. so this is the most dynamic way

Comment: @SimonS Please do not post or comment shorthand aliases. `gci -r` --> `Get-ChildItem -Recurse` provides much better understanding of the code you suggest, especially for people just getting into PowerShell.